# STM32 runtime Variable value manipulation

Tags: stm32, memory, calibration, swd, st-link

So basically I am not an expert, altho I think I have a good basis of knowledge.

I am using an STM32 Cortex 4 (discovery) for a hobby CNC machining application.

So lets assume we have a SW under development. The SW is used to control a system, lets say some actuators based on sensor values, using simple PI (lets ignore the rest of signal processing for now).

Now lets assume that I want to try out several P & I values based on the analysis and see how the system performs.
My question is, what kind of mechanism am I looking at here, in order to be able to change the content of a global variable in my SW during the runtime, without re-flashing.

Is SWD (and JTAG) only clean option? Or would be possible to use any other serial com and if yes, could you provide some links or short examples which could point me "How it is done?".

I have checked thinks like IAP and DFU in case I need to reflash it. I also checked STM Studio as an example (here I believe on-board ST link of Nucleo is used?)

Regards

Comment: The STM32 MCUs all have RAM.  Store your value in RAM and modify it to test different scenarios.  This assumes you have some sort of input device to trigger the change.

Comment: Is a screen and a rotary encoder no good? You could flash LEDs as a cheap output device.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments!
@jwh20 I have never intentionally done something like that. So I will check. Do you have any good basis to start with? Some documentation to read etc?

Comment: @enhzflep That would work as long as I have few parameters to be calibrated. However in my case I have over 20 of them (more planned in the future). Additionally, I have some 2D maps. So unfortunately that would not bring me far. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have serial communication between a PC and your stm32 device? If so you can read a new value from the serial port on the stm32 device and write it into a global variable, or a static variable (which is a global in duration, but restricted in terms of where it is accessible). Use putty or similar to type the new value in. Once you are happy you can tell the stm32 to store the value in its internal flash memory.

Comment: Can you modify the code for the STM32? Or are you looking at a solution without modifying code?

Answer (score 2):

JTAG/SWD can be used to change variables.

Or you can make a simple serial console that allows to change the variables. Either with text commands like "p 3.14159" or simply make different letters change a value by some amount and print the new value out.

Same can be achieved with pushbuttons and LCD, or by blinking LEDs, if you have no other interface.

Comment: hi @Justme, thanks for reply. That would work indeed. But its not a "way to go solution" once you have over 50 parameters to calibrate. I am looking for something similar as it is used for example in automotive, when 2D maps are calibrated to find that "sweet spot".
There has to be a way to manipulate at least RAM in a very simple way, to test out effect of changed global variables on your system.

Comment: You can use the serial console to dump in a CSV file if you want, or upload the parameters in binary, either one at a time or a block at a time. You can program it to receive any kind of data in any kind of form you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Is SWD (and JTAG) only clean option? Or would be possible to use any
> other serial com and if yes, could you provide some links or short
> examples which could point me "How it is done?".

You have to have access to the code, or you have to reverse engineer the code.

The easiest way is to run a debugger with SWD/JTAG, in runtime any variable can be changed with most debuggers.

Another way is with software, a variable could be updated from any source, UART (RS232,RS485) or USB, memory or GPIO.

If you don't have access to the code, it would be a lot of work to change the variable in the memory space, because you'd have to find out where it is in the code, insert your own code to change it, essentially hacking the device.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check XCP/CCP toolset for your controller, that may help you. Actually, it is defacto in Automotive applications.